# Reformatting Excel datastructure from multiple rows in columns/rows format

Tags: excel, data-structures, reformatting, vba

I have the following case: I got data in an format like:
date - timestamp - value where there are 29 values per day, so date stayes the same
What i need is something like:
date 1 per row
timestamp times 29 for each timestamp in a day as columns
values where date and timestamp meets

Is there a way to reformat the structure completely? As the data is pretty big (10 years, 29 data per day) it would take ages to do manually. I need it in the normal excel format as result so i can easily import the data in c#.
What i have:

```
22.03.2018    08:00    200
22.03.2018    08:30    202
22.03.2018    ...
22.03.2018    22:00    120
23.03.2018    08:00    12
```

What I want:

```
              08:00  08:30  ...  22:00
22.03.2018    200    202    ...    120
23.03.2018    12
```

Every help would be appreciated :)
Br

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you want.  Could you give a sample of what your data actually is and what the desired output would be for that sample?

Comment: Hi @Evan, the data is the following:
22.03.2018 | 08:00 | 200
22.03.2018 | 08:30 | 202 and so on
...
22.03.2018 | 22:00 | 120
23.03.2018  08:00  | 12 
| stands for a new cell. what i would need is something like that:
                   | 08:00 | 08:30 | ... | 22:00
22.03.2018 | 200    | 202    | ... | 120
23.03.2018 | 12 ...

Comment: So you have multiple "rows" of data in the same row, is that why "12" means new row?

Comment: This sounds like a range.parse or range.texttocolumns problem but your sample data is unintelligible and I cannot even determine whether you've provided expected results.

Comment: Hello @Jeeped, I have provided further information in the question itself. i want the data of multiple rows (with the same date) to be reformatted in a single row with the date.

Comment: You could import the file, or use text to Columns feature in excel with a pivot grid to do the same thing and not have to code it?

Comment: I have no idea how that would work, but thanks for the information. As i want to import the data after the rearrangement into c# - is this possible with the pivot grid - and what do you mean by import the file - where?

Comment: Import meaning use "From Text" in the Data tab of excel. Im not aware of how you brought the file into excel. If the data is already into individual cells, then just use the Pivot Grid. Set the "Dates" as rows, "Times" as Columns and use "Values" as data

Comment: I tried using the pivot table but the result is not exactly what i need as the data are not easily accessable/ editable, so the original idea on reformating it as vba formula would be much appreciated.